# How to get ip adress and port in web service

Tags: java, spring-ws

I have spring-ws deployed in my server. There is some task every day which should write ip adress and the port of server where this application run. How I can get this information ? I try `InetAddress` but with no success. There is no port.

Comment: I found somethiing in wsTemplate wsTemplate.getDestinationProvider().getDestination().getHost() but this always gives me just localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting a hold of the servletRequest should be enough to put you on track to get the IP address.

```
TransportContext ctx = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
HttpServletConnection conn = (HttpServletConnection )ctx.getConnection();
HttpServletRequest request = conn.getHttpServletRequest();
```

Use this code in an interceptor defined on your ws. Now you can simply call

```
request. getRemoteAddr();
```

to get the IP.

Comment: hm but I dont want to get ip from incerceptor. I have task and when I copy this code there I got NPE