# SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor: how log client remote URL

Tags: java, jax-ws, spring-ws

I have a custom `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor` to log the soap envelope of the ws service calls using a transformer.
Is there a way to log the remote URL of the call in this class? (ex. ip address)
The best is to manipulate something like HttpServletRequest.

In context I have:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean id="envelopeLoggingInterceptor" class="path.to.my.CustomSoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor">
        <property name="loggerName" value="myLogger" />
        <property name="logRequest" value="true" />
        <property name="logResponse" value="true" />
        <property name="logFault" value="true" />
    </bean>
</sws:interceptors>
```

My `CustomSoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor`:

```
public class CustomSoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor extends SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor {
    @Override
    protected void logMessageSource(String message, Source source) throws TransformerException {
        if (source != null){
            Transformer trf = this.getTransformerFactory().newTransformer();
            trf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            trf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult stream = new StreamResult(writer);
            trf.transform(source, stream);
            writer.flush();

            this.logger.debug(message + stream.getWriter().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9114236/956884

Comment: thanks evandongen, it works like a charm. Next time i will search more accurately before open new Question.